# Маршрутизация nodejs express

Tags: node.js, javascript

Собственно код

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/projects/:project', routes.projects);
app.get('/projects/:project/:img', routes.projectsImg);
```

Все вроде верно, но при попытки зайти на `'/'` сервер пытается обработать все запросы, причем в качестве `:project` и `:img` пытается получить путь картинки логотипа, который из за этого не может подключиться... В чем беда, подскажите)

Comment: Что делает routes.index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена.
Картинка логотипа лежала в `/projects/logo.png`.
При попытки получить картинку сервер пытался ее обработать с помощью `app.get('/projects/:project', routes.projects);` и из за этого все ломалось.